# Where is the 0=1 bug coming from in this Mathematica code?

Tags: model, wolfram-mathematica, mathematical-optimization, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to build a simple voter model. I need to build a matrix whose values are given by a function. Then aggregate them (in this case simple average) to determine the result (simple 1 or 0). Then determine the deviance of the result from the average. I am stuck because whenever there is a 0 resulting from my if statement it is treated as a 1 by the subtraction. Please help.
*Bonus: if there is a way to update a variable for every fourth row of the matrix and have that value carry over to better simulate and election it would be much appreciated. 
Thank you in advance,
Charles

```
m = 3
n = 5
p := RandomInteger[]
c = Table[p, {i, m}, {j, n}]
t = Total[c, {2}] 
avg = t/n
Function[If[0.5 <= # <= 1, v = 1, v = 0]] /@ avg
d = Abs[v - avg]
Sum[d, i]
```

Comment: your `Function` resets `v` for each item in `avg` , so it ends up with the last value. Is that intended or do you expect `v` to be a list?

Comment: Yes I want it to calculate the distance from a 0,1 approximation on each value in v separately. The output vector d is 1x3 like I expected but the difference isn't calculating properly.

Comment: you could simply do `v=Round[avg]`

Comment: Thanks that works and is much cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace last three lines:

```
...
v = Function[If[0.5 <= # <= 1, 1, 0]] /@ avg
d = Abs[v - avg] 
Total[d]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help @ChrisDegnen. It works and is versatile. Hopefully I won't make the same mistake again.